# Unable to access related eloquent models when calling the user object through Auth::User() in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm just running through the process of upgrading my app to Laravel 5. I was using the Laravel 4 user authentication library, along with my own 'Profile' model, for storing user profile information, defined like this:

**User model:**

```
class User extends Eloquent implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract {

    //...
    public function Profile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Profile'); 
    }
    //..

}
```

**Profile model:**

```
class Profile extends Eloquent {

   //...
   public function User()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo('User');
   }
   //...

}
```

Previously (when the app was Laravel 4), I would be able to access the profile for the logged in user by loading the user object through the Auth facade:

```
$user = Auth::user();
echo $user->profile->picture;
```

However, since upgrading to Laravel 5 this has been throwing a `Trying to get property of non-object` error.

I am able to load the profile, via the user, if I load the user object directly through the user model, like this:

```
$user = User::findOrFail(Auth::user()->id)->first();
echo $user->profile->picture;
```

...but this seems like a long-winded way of doing it.

Is there a better way, or is there something I'm missing? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Not sure but as per documentation I feel it should be Auth::user() instead of Auth::User()

Comment: My mistake in writing this post - I was actually using `Auth::user();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's what I think it is, then you might need to update `config/auth.php`'s `model` option to be your user model's class name.

This property is the model that laravel's auth driver will use. By default, it is `App\User`.

Comment: Well spotted! I changed it to `'model' => 'User',` and it's working again. I think I'm going to have to bring my namespace setup to be more inline with how Laravel works. Thanks for your help.